# Vertically align 50% of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to vertically align a `div` to `50%` of the viewport, no matter how long the document is.

You can see an example here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Comment: What does the link have to do with it?

Comment: the lightboxes are centered vertically on viewport

Comment: Use one ralative container with two divs, both absolute, first -50% top, second 50% top, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Box offsets properties can be used to obtain this effect.

> This property specifies how far an absolutely positioned box's top
> margin edge is offset below the top edge of the box's containing
> block.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props

---

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMwBE/)

#### CSS

```
#centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px; /* arbitrary */
    width: 600px; /* arbitrary */
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery example that will center a div regardless of it's height and width.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/dzSPN/120/

```
function animateHight(newHeight){
    $('div#centered').animate({'height': newHeight, 'margin-top': -newHeight/2}, 600, function(){animateWidth(100);animateHight(100);});
}
function animateWidth(newWidth){
    $('div#centered').animate({'width': newWidth, 'margin-left': -newWidth/2}, 600);
}
```